# jquery grid hyper links not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am invoking a grid with a custom add button in the caption bar.
I have a column in the grid with a hyperlink.

The hyperlink I am calling as:

```
 var cal="<a href='javascript: showSubList("+headerID+")'>"+headerID+"</a>";
 $("#BsGrid").jqGrid('setRowData',i,{bs_list_id:cal});
```

I am invoking the add row as:

```
jQuery("#BsGrid").jqGrid('addRow',{
    rowID : "new_row",
    initdata : {},
    position :"first",
    useDefValues : true,
    useFormatter : false,
    //addRowParams : {extraparam:{}}
    beforeShowForm:"",
    keys : false,

});
//var sav='<img style="padding-top:2px;" src="jq/img/save1.gif"  
                             // height="16" width="16" >';

var sav='<a href="javascript: saveAddList()"><img style="padding-top:2px;" 
               src="jq/img/save1.gif"  height="16" width="16" ></a>';

var can='<a href="javascript: cancel()"><img style="padding-top:2px;" 
              src="jq/img/cancel.png"  height="16" width="16" ></a>';

$("#BsGrid").jqGrid('setRowData',"new_row",{act:sav+can});
```

with a save and cancel buttons in the row.

when I click on the cancel button, the hyperlink column is showing all appended valued as 18)'>18)'>18)'>18)'>18  where ID is 18...   what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible to create an example using http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

`setRowData` is for updating values. Based on how you say 'add rows' but do a setRowData, try `addRowData(rowId, data)`. Also, based on the documentation there is no addRow method. Change to `$('#jqid').addRowData(rowId, { colName: value }, position)` Use AddRowData's 3rd parameter to set the position in the grid.